# Nginx returning 403 when using Twitter URL shortener

Tags: twitter, nginx, dns, http-status-code-403, url-shortener

Going to https://example.com directly works fine. When you tweet that link to someone and it gets shortened to something like https://t.co/fBUFn9ap4e, they click the link and the URL changes to https://example.com, but the server returns a 403 error. Why would that be?

Nginx config:

```
upstream example.com {
    server 127.0.0.1:8000;
    keepalive 8;
}

server {

    listen 0.0.0.0:80;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;

}

server {
    #listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name example.com;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/example.com.log;

    root /var/www/example.com/client/public;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/my_domain.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/my_domain.key;

    location / {
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

        proxy_pass http://example.com;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

    location ~* \.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|cur|gz|svg|svgz|mp4|ogg|ogv|webm|htc|webp)$ {
        expires 1M;
        access_log off;
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
    }

    location ~* \.(?:css|js)$ {
        expires 1y;
        access_log off;
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
    }

    location ~* \.(?:rss|atom)$ {
        expires 1h;
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
    }

    location ~* \.(?:manifest|appcache|html?|xml|json)$ {
        expires -1;
    }

    valid_referers none blocked example.com *.example.com;
    if ($invalid_referer) {
        return 403;
    }

 }

server {

    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name www.example.com;
    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;

}
```

Comment: is your server behind a cloudflare service plan?

Comment: nope, just a digital ocean box with nginx proxying to a node app

Comment: could you edit your question and add nginx configuration details? pls don't forget to comment out qualifying names and ip addresses... do you use proxy_pass with ip:port or as direct connect to app? (found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30097334/nodejs-on-nginx-not-working-without-a-port-number-in-the-url )

Comment: thanks for the help, turns out when I checked the config I totally missed the bit that says, in plain English, return 403 to unknown referrers!

Answer (score 1):

*slaps forehead in shame*

Can't believe I missed this:

```
valid_referers none blocked example.com *.example.com;
if ($invalid_referer) {
    return 403;
}
```

dumb dumb dumb dumb dumb. Get more sleep.

Comment: simple solutions are the best!